# Appcelerator Package generates icon files with illegal characters

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to upload my app to the Apple Store but whenever I attempt to upload the archive I receive this error:

`ERROR ITMS-90328: "Your package contains a file 'app.app/Images/Icon ' with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names."
ERROR ITMS-90328: "Your package contains a file 'app.app/Images/Icon ' with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names."`

I am using Titanium SDK 6.0.3GA. I don't know what is generating these files or why. Any help with a fix or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wanted to add this for future googlers, I had the same error due to a SPACE that was inserted (probably by me / accident) at the end of the application name. It gets all the way to upload completed before erroring.

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing your icon file in your app/Images/Icon folder? You can check out this doc link for icon file.

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-src-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-BuildscriptsforiOSicons

Hope this helps.

Comment: no I am using `DefaultIcon-ios.png` in the root of the project folder so that it auto-generated my icons